running of overlay modification-hooks stop at the middle of undo: is this a bug?
Here is a simpilified example: with following code, I create a buffer/file and run M-x buffer-overlay to insert text and put on overlay with modification-hooks, and then run M-x serialize-to-buffer to delete and insert new text. After this, I run undo to revert to the old text. I would expect buffer-update-hook to run before the revert and after the revert to the old text. However, the message output is shown below, indicating that the buffer-update-hook apparently only ran upon the buffer reverting in the middle of undo (between delete and new text insert). Why is that? Why the hook did not run after the whole undo (i.e. after reverting to the old text)? I thought I already combined the delete and the insert into a single undo unit with combine-change-calls . Additionally, why the hook did not run after reverting back to the old text? In the end, how can I refactor the code to make sure the hook runs only upon the finish of the whole unit of undo?
Test example code:
(defun buffer-update-hook (ov after beg end &optional length)
  (message "--- after? %S beg: %d end: %d" after beg end)
  (let ((inhibit-modification-hooks nil)) ; just make sure it was not somehow set to t
  (when after                            ; after the text change
    (message "--- buffer %s" (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max))))))


(defun serialize-to-buffer ()
  "Update the buffer region with the SGF string representation of game."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((ov (car (overlays-in (point-min) (point-max))))
         (beg (point-min))
         (end (point-max))
         ;; disable all modification hooks including the overlay
         ;; modification hooks temporarily.
         (inhibit-modification-hooks t)
         ;; (inhibit-read-only t)
         )
      ;; (setq buffer-read-only nil)
      (save-excursion
        ;; Wraps the operation in undo-boundary calls to ensure it's
        ;; treated as a distinct unit in the undo list
        (undo-boundary)
        ;; group the delete and insert operations into a single undo unit.
        (combine-change-calls beg end
          (delete-region beg end)
          (insert "new-inserted"))
        (undo-boundary))))

(defun buffer-overlay ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "old-text")
  (remove-overlays)
  (let ((ov (make-overlay (point-min) (point-max) nil nil t)))
    (overlay-put ov 'modification-hooks '(buffer-update-hook))))

Message output:
---after? nil beg: 1 end: 13
---after? t beg: 1 end: 1
--- buffer 

